# Object is possibly 'undefined' typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to access the value from an object. But I get the following error.

> Object is possibly 'undefined' typescript

My TypeScript code:

```
import { SqlClient } from 'msnodesqlv8';

declare var require: any;

const sql: SqlClient = require('msnodesqlv8');

const connectionString =
  'server=.,1433;Database=emps;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}';
const query = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sample] WHERE id = 117';

sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
  console.log(rows);   // this works fine, but when i try to access its value using object key, it fails
  console.log(rows[0].Id);  // this fails
});
```

This works fine in JavaScript. What is the TypeScript way of doing it.

Comment: wh ynot check for undefined before the log ?

Comment: Use an `if` statement

Comment: `declare var require: any;

const sql: SqlClient = require('msnodesqlv8');` is very wrong (FYI). It most definitely needs to be `import sql = require('msnodesqlv8');` or `import sql from 'msnodesqlv8';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because if the `rows` array doesn't contain any elements, then `rows[0]` will be undefined.  Two possible solutions:

1) Check that it actually has data, e.g.

```
if (rows[0]) {
    console.log(rows[0].Id)
}
```

2) Disable the `strict` or `strictNullChecks` option in your `tsconfig.json` (see more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). This will silence the error, but you'll get a runtime error if it actually *is* undefined, so you may want to check the value instead unless you're absolutely certain it will always have data.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to reduce strictness. If you need to override it on a specific value, adjust the type of that value.